Ping broken. Help, please?
I am attempting to install a web server from home.
The machine is a BOSGAME ECOLITE SERIES MINI PC running UBUNTU 24.04.1.
I have a Google Router model GJ2CQ.
When I go to this site:
https://dnschecker.org/ping-ipv4.php
And check my WAN IP address of "73.92.178.22"
I get the message:
"Destination Host Unreachable Packet Summary

Sent:5    

Received:0   

Loss:100%   

Time:4107 ms"

On my Google Router, under Network Settings, Advanced Networking, Port Management, I have two records:
80->80 and 443->443 for my ubuntu machine LAN IP "192.168.86.119"
I have my UFW Uncomplicated Fire Wall set to allow incoming, outgoing, and routed.
root@ccai:/# sudo ufw status verbose

Status: active

Logging: on (low)

Default: allow (incoming), allow (outgoing), allow (routed)

New profiles: skip

root@ccai:/# 

Any clues would be helpful to get my ping working.

What WAN IP address does your Google Router report? does it show the same "73.92.178.22" anywhere in the router's settings or status screens? If it does, then more investigation needs to be done, but if it does not, then it's a duplicate of https://superuser.com/a/1857422 and https://superuser.com/a/1857163 and many others.

Your computer or port forwardings are not involved with Ping. Only the router is. It may block ICMP Echo Requests.

Like @DanielB said, it may be because you block ICMP requests. This could help you : https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleWiFi/comments/18umodu/how_to_enable_icmp_traffic_on_a_google_wifi_router/

Thank you for the responses! The Google Router states: "Device Settings: Wi-Fi Information: WAN IP: 73.92.178.22 LAN IP: 192.168.86.1 Model: GJ2CQ Software Version: 14150.376.32" ... I will look at the other clues above next. Thanks again for any help. I've been suck on this for seven days.
